# Citation difficulties

Tags: citing

I am using `\usepackage{apacite}`
and for following citations I use `\cite{Author}`

Although I have tried the `\fullcite{}` and`\shortcite` nothing has changed in the lenghts of the citations.

Furthermore do I want to list a reference as

> According to `Name of Author (year)` this theory has developed.

I found the commands of `\citep` and `\citet` which unfortunately don't work for me...

If you could help me that'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

with bibtex and created the commands:

```
%Definitions of commands for the citation
\def\CiteAuthorParYear#1{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1}) }
\def\CiteParAuthorYear#1{(\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1}))}
```

Par, means parenthesis and so the first is probably what you are looking for.

Keep the second and adjust it to your needs to cite inside parenthesis or brackets, or whatever

Answer (score 0):

The macros `\citet` ("textual citation" -- something like `Smith (1999)`) and `\citep` ("parenthetic citation" -- something like `(Smith 1999)`) are provided by the `natbib` citation management package.

If you wish to use these macros while using the `apacite` citation management package instead (along with the `apacite` bibliography style, right?), you need to load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa`:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

One should never load both `apacite` and `natbib`.

Comment: I now used \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} and it works fine. thank you for that, but why do you say I should never do that? or did you mean I should not load \usepackage{apacite} and \usepackage{natbib} at the same time? You seem to be the real MVP by the way. Thank you a thousand times. Greetings from St. Gallen.

Comment: @thebilly - You're welcome. :-) By the way, I wrote "One should never load both `apacite` and `natbib`" -- what's ambiguous about that?